# ckeditor content jumps, shakes, or shifts up on resize

Tags: ckeditor

Hey I could really use some help.

I'm using ckeditor 4 and I've recently noticed whenever i have content and i move cursor to the end of content and hit enter or do a shift enter, the entire content briefly jumps up maybe 10-20px then lands back where it should be. I have autogrow enabled and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with ckeditor's resize method because i tried excluding autogrow and manually writing my own autogrow and the same thing happened. If your cursor is not at the immediate end of the content and you hit enter or shift+enter, there is NO jump in the content which is perplexing...

I thought it might have to do with the css. I use my own customized css file and changed the margin: 20px in the body tag to 0px margin all sides and instead put a left and right padding of 10px, because i noticed in IE if you click the margins of a paragraph nothing happens (no selection is made), but if you switch to padding instead of margin it works great. However when i switched the css back to margin: 20px only i still have the shake

here is config.js

```
config.removeButtons = '';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow,liststyle,dialog,panelbutton,colorbutton,justify,indent,indentlist,undo';
config.allowedContent = true;
config.removePlugins = 'resize,elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

and here is the table initialization

```
    replaceElem.html( "<texarea name='nLawTableRow" + uniqueRowId + "' class='cLawTextArea cLawTableRow" + uniqueRowId + "'>" + text + "</textarea>" ); 
// initialize the editor            
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( "nLawTableRow" + uniqueRowId, {
    toolbar: [{ name: 'group1', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', /*'Superscript',*/ 'Strike', 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ]}, // temporarily remove superscript
              { name: 'group2', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'Indent', 'Outdent' ]}, // remove ordered list for now
              { name: 'group4', items: [ /*'Undo', 'Redo',*/ 'Maximize' ]},
    ],
    autoGrow_onStartup: true, // grows the editor to fit its content when you ini it 
    autoGrow_minHeight: 0, // minimum height of the editor, setting it to 0 just means theres no min height, if  there is no content height will not be 
    fillEmptyBlocks: false,
    contentsCss: '/www/public/css/ckeditor_more.css', // get styles from this document instead of default
    enterMode: 1, // enter creates a paragraph as well
});
```

and here is the relevant part of the custom css file I use. i modified the body tag style here and created a new p tag style as well. everything else about the css file is identical to the default contents.css

```
.cke_editable p {
    margin-top: 14px !important;
    margin-bottom: 14px !important;
}

body.cke_editable
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 14px;

    /* Text color */
    color: #333;

    /* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
    background-color: #fff;

    /* ME: set margins specifically, used to be margin: 20, now left and right 10, no top or bottom because paragraphs already have their own margins */
    /* for left and right can't use margin have to use PADDING because in IE if you click on a margin instead of paragraph it doesnt make any selection, which
    can make it very difficult to select start of a paragraph or far left of a a sentence. using paddding instead of margin solves that problem, hope it doesnt cause 
    other problems because the default is to use margin for left right which seems to work fine in Chrome but not IE I*/

    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important; /* ME: permantently prevents any scrollbars which can happen sometimes with page resize , maybe a bug */
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

PS I found a link https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10981
where someone seems to describe the same or similar issue but there is no solution.